# sending infinity number of checkbox values to text

Tags: javascript, text, checkbox

I have a table with n number of rows with checkboxes and a  what i want to do is if i select a checkbox the value should go to the text area, so i stored all elements in an array first, but it isnt happening, as you can see i added alerts as well to check it out. please help.

```
window.onload = function () { 
    var oRows = document.getElementById('rnatable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var iRowCount = oRows.length;
    alert('Your table has ' + iRowCount + ' rows.');

    var i = 0;
    cb = new Array(iRowCount);
    while (i <= iRowCount) {
        var id = 'check'+ i;
        cb[i] = document.getElementById(id);
        i++;
    }
    //alert('Your table has ' + cb[i].value + ' rows.');
    for(var a=0; a < iRowCount; a++) {
        var fasta = document.getElementById('fasta');
        if(cb[a].checked) {
            fasta.value = cb.value + ","; 
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Your code is in an `onload` handler, but are you saying you want the values to go to the textarea in response to the user clicking on the checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing an error in the console?  I suspect that when `while (i <= iRowCount)` runs when `i === iRowCount` that `document.getElementById(id)` isn't yielding a result, and that then when you use that value, bad things happen.

Also, each lap through the `fasta` loop overwrites the previous value.  You probably want something like `fasta.value += cb.value + ",";` instead.

Comment: The `<= iRowCount` implies that the IDs are numbered starting from one whereas the `i = 0` initialization implies that the IDs are numbered starting from zero; that confusion is part of the problem no doubt.

Comment: indeed.  Yet `i = 0` is the initialization.

Comment: thank you all for your inputs, another user mistapink helped me with the answer check it out http://jsfiddle.net/ZfmNw/1/